# Unable to download attachments from outlook using Python || Python 3.10

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to download an attachment from outlook with a specific Subject line. It shows finished, but no attachment is getting downloaded. Below attached is my code, kindly help if I am missing something.

```
# import libraries
import win32com.client
import re
import datetime
import  pathlib2 as pathlib

# set up connection to outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
today_date = str(datetime.date.today())
while True:
  try:
    current_sender = str(message.Sender).lower()
    current_subject = str(message.Subject).lower()
    # find the email from a specific sender with a specific subject
    # condition
    if re.search('AllSalons was executed at',current_subject) != None:
    #if re.search('AllSalons was executed at',current_subject) != None and    re.search(sender_name,current_sender) != None:
      print(current_subject) # verify the subject
      print(current_sender)  # verify the sender
      attachments = message.Attachments
      attachment = attachments.Item(1)
      attachment_name = str(attachment).lower()
      attachment.SaveASFile(pathlib.path + 'C:\\Users\\UserTest\\Desktop\\Folder\\Subject Line\\Nov' + attachment_name)
    else:
      pass
    message = messages.GetNext()
  except:
    message = messages.GetNext()
  break 
print("Finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that a valid file path is passed to the `SaveAsFile` method of the `Attachment` class:

```
attachment.SaveASFile(pathlib.path + 'C:\\Users\\UserTest\\Desktop\\Folder\\Subject Line\\Nov' + attachment_name)
```

Make sure the folder exists on the disk and the file name doesn't contain forbidden symbols in its name. Windows and Linux don't allow some symbols in file names, see [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for more information.

Second, instead of iterating over all items in the Outlook folder and checking the `Subject` property value you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. So, in that case you can deal only with items that correspond to your search criteria and iterate over them. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thank you man, for helping me with it...Means a alot!

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating two paths, one of them is a a fully qualified path (`"c:\"`..). The only way it can ever work is if `pathlib.path` is empty.

Also, replace the line

```
attachment_name = str(attachment).lower()
```

with

```
attachment_name = str(attachment.FileName).lower()
```

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!